# Java Swing read file to textfield

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I'm trying to read a txt file using Java. I wanted to separate the contents.

Example the content of the txt file is:

```
[t]
Harry Potter
[a]
J.K Rowling

[c]
Once Upon a time
there was a wizard name Harry Potter
The End.
```

I want to put the texts with `[c]` in a textfield named `txtContent` but what happens now is that only the first line is passed in the txtContent

```
private void btnRetireveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String filename=txtFilename.getText()+".txt";
    int x=1;
    String text=null;
    try (BufferedReader fw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename))))
    {
        String s;
        while((s = fw.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(s.equals("[a]"))
            {
                String author = fw.readLine(); //read the next line after [a]
                txtAuthor.setText(author);
                break;
            }
        }
        while((s = fw.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(s.equals("[c]"))
            {
                String content = fw.readLine(); //read the next line after [a]
                txtContent.setText(content);
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `BufferedReader`, read each line and make determinations about what action should be taken based on the last known state...

Comment: is this right? BufferedReader Search=new BufferedReader(fw);
            while(Search.readLine().contains("[a]"))
            {
                txtAuthor.read(Search,evt);
            }

Comment: It depends if you want to process the remained of the file or or not.  Also, `readLine` will return `null` when it reaches the end of the file...

Comment: @newbie07, why don't you simply use [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)?

Comment: @Arvind I don't know haha I think because I'm new in Java and I don't know a lot of stuff :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you detect if you are currently at `[a]` line then you can then read the `nextLine` and break the loop.

Use `BufferedReader` instead of `FileReader`

**sample:**

```
try (BufferedReader fw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("text.txt"))))
{
    String s;
    while((s = fw.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(s.equals("[a]"))
        {
            String author = fw.readLine(); //read the next line after [a]
            System.out.println(author); //the line after [a]
        }
        if(s.equals("[c]"))
        {
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            while((s = fw.readLine()) != null)
                content.append(s + " ");
            System.out.println(content); //the line after [c]
        }
    }
} catch (IOException exp)
{
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What happens if `[a]` is the last line ;) - You might want to verify the format of the file as well, as the original question was formatting nightmare :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer it wont happen as long the textfile is correct.

Comment: You're to trusting ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer or maybe it is already on that format that he dont need to add on it nor change it. :))

Comment: Based on the OP's comments, it might in the format of `[a] ...` and not `[a]\n...` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yup but that is 50/50 he is not sure in comments.. :)), well im just gonna wait for his update.

Comment: Never assume correct input.  It's 90% of why a routine fails.  This type of error is akin to believing that a null reference will never be passed into "setX(...)", and yet the entire reason we have "setX(...)" instead of "Object.x = ..." is because we know the object will eventually require data validation.  It's really not any different here....

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin how can I pass a StringBuilder to a Jtextfield?

Comment: @newbie07 content.toString();

Comment: @EdwinBuck roger that :))

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin if(s.equals("[c]"))
                {
                    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                    while((s = fw.readLine()) != null)
                        content.append(s + " ");
                    txtContent.setText(content.toString()); //the line after [c]
                }

it doesn't show in the textfield

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56913/discussion-between-rod-algonquin-and-newbie07).